# How to use the `writeThis()` construct in Chapel

Tags: formatting, chapel

I have a class in Chapel, and I want to let it control it's own print statement.  So for instance

```
class Noob {
  var name: string,  experience:int;
  // constructor
}
```

Later, I want to do something like

```
me = new Noob('brian', 0)
writeln(me)

> Hi, my name is Brian and I have 0 years experience
```

It looks like [this](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/builtins/internal/ChapelIO.html#the-readthis-writethis-and-readwritethis-methods) should help, but I can't quite get the `readThis()` method to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a `writeThis(f)` method to override the default `writeln` behavior for an object:

```
class Noob {
  var name: string,  experience:int;

  proc writeThis(f) {
    f.writef('Hi, my name is %s and I have %t years experience',
             this.name, this.experience);
  }
}

var noob = new Noob('ben', 2);

writeln(noob);
```

You can also use the `<~>` operator in a `readWriteThis(f)` method to handle both reading and writing of the object:

```
class Noob {
  var name: string,  experience:int;

  proc readWriteThis(f) {
    f <~> 'Hi, my name is %s and I have %t years experience'.format(this.name, this.experience);
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed a  **`new Noob( 'ben', 2 );`** [ +1 ] Sir, a good joke!